# Error in ASP SQL

Tags: sql, database, asp-classic, eof

The error says:
Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

I have code that receives an id, which is a number, from another site and will edit the data that matches the id.

```
<body>    
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
    <!-- #include file="header.html"-->
        </tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr >
<td style="width:885px" class="style2" >
<%
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\library\database.mdb"
cid=Request.Form("number")
if Request.form("firstname")="" then
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  rs.open "SELECT * FROM users WHERE no='" & cid & "'",conn
  %>
<form method="post" action="change.asp">
<table>
  <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
  <tr>
  <td><% Response.Write(x.name)%></td>
  <td><input name='<%Response.Write(x.name)%>' value='<%Response.Write(x.value)%>'></td>
  <%next%>
  </tr>
  </table>
    <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Update record">
  </form>
<%
else
    sql="UPDATE users SET "
    sql=sql & "firstname='" & Request.Form("firstname") & "',"
    sql=sql & "lastname='" & Request.Form("lastname") & "',"
    sql=sql & "Gender='" & Request.Form("Gender") & "'"
  sql=sql & " WHERE no='" & cid & "'"
  on error resume next
  conn.Execute sql
  if err<>0 then
    response.write("No update permissions!")
  else
    response.write("Record " & cid & " was updated!")
  end if
end if
conn.close
%>


</td>
<td><!--#include file="sideMenu.html"-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Omar, are you aware that this code has a major security vulnerability? The user can type anything as "cid" and it will be passed directly to the database (including commands to delete tables, return passwords, etc.) Of course, you've got your entire database under wwwroot, so a user could probably just download it anyway... I hope this isn't real production code.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <body>    
  <table style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
      <!-- #include file="header.html"-->
          </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
  <tr >
  <td style="width:885px" class="style2" >
  <%
  set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
  conn.Open "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\library\database.mdb"
  cid=Request.Form("number")
  if Request.form("firstname")="" then
  set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rs.open "SELECT * FROM users WHERE no=" & cid ,conn

    If rs.EOF Then

       Response.Write "There is no data for this user in the database"

    Else

    %>
  <form method="post" action="change.asp">
  <table>

    <%for each x in rs.Fields%>
     <tr>
       <td><%=x.name%></td>
       <td><input name='<%=x.name%>' value='<%=x.value%>'></td>
     </tr>          
    <%next%>        

  </table>
      <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Update record">
    </form>
  <%

  End If

  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing

  else
      sql="UPDATE users SET "
      sql=sql & "firstname='" & Request.Form("firstname") & "',"
      sql=sql & "lastname='" & Request.Form("lastname") & "',"
      sql=sql & "Gender='" & Request.Form("Gender") & "'"
    sql=sql & " WHERE no=" & cid
    on error resume next
    conn.Execute sql
    if err<>0 then
      response.write("No update permissions!")
    else
      response.write("Record " & cid & " was updated!")
    end if
  end if
  conn.close
  %>


  </td>
  <td><!--#include file="sideMenu.html"-->
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
```

Comment: still has the same error 
the error in this line line

    <td><input name='<%Response.Write(x.name)%>' value='<%Response.Write(x.value)%>'></td>

Comment: line number 25 
    <td><input name='<%Response.Write(x.name)%>' value='<%Response.Write(x.value)%>'></td>

Comment: thanks for help but still have the same problem in the same line

Comment: because your select statement isn't returning anything.  You can use the `If rs.EOF Then` to see if there are any rows being returned first.

Comment: what about line number 15 its also check if its empty

if Request.form("firstname")="" then

Comment: that is only checking the form data, not the `SELECT` statement from your database.

Comment: output is there is no data in your database

Comment: but i really have data in the data base 
do you think there is error in the connection

Comment: Have you tried checking the database to see if this select statement actually works?

Comment: Also if the `no` column is numeric, then try removing your quotes around the cid. `no=" & cid`

Answer (score 0):

Permission problem? Check if IIs has permission to read the Database tables.
Also, at this line

```
if Request.form("firstname")="" then
```

I usually use

```
if Request.form("firstname") & ""="" then
```